# Microsoft Cognitive Services - Speech recognition, Transport Error

Tags: speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

Simple question, how do I setup the [default Speech to text sample app](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Speech-STT-Windows) to work? 
I have followed all the instructions:

And got my keys from here:[image]
Pasted them here : (The key is redacted just to be safe).

[image]

That's the output of the program with the correct key instead of PASTED KEY HERE.

And let's say, that this does not work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing via RDP?  Check https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Speech-STT-Windows/issues/13, where the solution is to enable local microphone when using RDP to another machine.